How to implement a custom identity provider based on LiteDb.Identity for a Blazor app?
I am trying to implement a LiteDb Identity provider. I have a template blazor app and I want to implement a custom Identity with LiteDB using https://github.com/quicksln/LiteDB.Identity. I managed to get to a certain point, but I get an error that I cannot fix.
This is my Program.cs
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    // Add services to the container.
    var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    builder.Services.AddLiteDBIdentity(connectionString);
    builder.Services.AddIdentity<LiteDbUser, LiteDbRole>();

    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.MapRazorPages();
    app.MapControllers();
    app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");


    app.Run();

this is my appsettings.json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Filename=./Data/IdentityLiteDB.dll;Password=1234;Connection=Shared"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}


I have replaced all instances of ApplicationUser to LiteDbUser (SignInManager, UserManager..) and I have an OidcConfigurationController. Should be enough, but when ran, I get this error
 System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer.IClientRequestParametersProvider' while attempting to activate 'OidcConfigurationController'.
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ThrowHelperUnableToResolveService(Type type, Type requiredBy)

Any tips how to proceed with this implementation?
